# Error with an image subscriber?

Tags: python, ros2, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS community,

I'm working with a USB2 camera module (Arducam AR0134), for the moment I use some of the constructor libraries to make my publisher and it work good and it gives me also ROS sensor_msgs/image.
**https://github.com/ArduCAM/ArduCAM_USB_Camera_Shield/tree/master/ROS/arducam_usb2_ros**

I'm able to see my image stream with "image_view". And for  the moment, I'm trying to add a subscriber in python to recover my images and save it. Since I'm working in this, I'm facing a lot of problems but I resolved the most but without receiving image in my subscriber because of some errors :

When using python I found in ros.tutorial that they use this instruction  import **roslib, roslib.load_manifest('my_package' )** so in my case I don't knew which kind of package I will use !!!!

Another problem, can we implement a ros publisher for the camera in python and subscriber in cpp !!!

Than you for answer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324114/error-with-an-image-subscriber-!/) by [massyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/41797/massyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't need to use `roslib.load_manifest` anywhere to get this working. Have a look at [this minimal example](https://gist.github.com/rethink-imcmahon/77a1a4d5506258f3dc1f) which subscribes to a topic and saves JPG images. You should be able to run this example successfully by only changing the `image_topic` variable.

Secondly yes you can publish and image with python and subscribe to it with cpp and the other way around, the messages are completely language agnostic.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [massyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/41797/massyp/) on 2019-05-28**:
Thank you very much, my program is working now without error.
I will just search were it save the images

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-05-28**:
If you run the node from a launch file they will be saved in `/home/<user_name>/.ros/` if started by rosrun they will be saved in the current path of the terminal.

Can you accept this answer by clicking the tick if it helped you solve the problem, thanks.